# Image display bug on Pycharm notebook, it is displayed in negative automatically

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I have a bug with the display of my images in my notebook on pycharm, indeed the image is automatically put with a negative filter:

```
import imageio

img = imageio.imread('imageio:astronaut.png')
img.shape, img.dtype

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Debug image')
plt.axis('off')
```

But on google colab for example the image is displayed normally with the same code.

do you have any solutions to this problem? Thanks

Comment: Code should be in question, not in links to images

Comment: Sorry I edited this

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer sorry that was just my theme on my IDE so change it if you have the same bug x)

Comment: Traditional. PyCharm 2022.1 (Pro) Build #PY-221.5080.212, built on April 12, 202. But the new Jupyter notebook interface is so great that the bug is minor.